How to use ESLint to warn me about top-level promises?
I want to get an ESLint warning for this program:
async function foo(){
  return;
}
async function bar(){
  foo(); // this is where I'd want the warning to occur
}

The reason I want this warning, is that inside bar() I probably meant to write await foo();. So the check would be that any statement should return nothing, or something that is not a Promise. How can I get ESLint to warn me about this?
I got weird (hard to debug) behavior once forgetting to add the await. Another time I had changed a function into an async one and missed adding an await at a call-site, again leading to flaky tests. I want to make sure I don't get hit by this again.

You are looking for the require-await rule. According to ESLint docs:

This rule warns async functions which have no await expression.

Here is an example:

Error:
/*eslint require-await: "error"*/

async function foo() {
    doSomething();
}

bar(async () => {
    doSomething();
});


Success:
/*eslint require-await: "error"*/

async function foo() {
    await doSomething();
}

bar(async () => {
    await doSomething();
});

function baz() {
    doSomething();
}

bar(() => {
    doSomething();
});

// Allow empty functions.
async function noop() {}




This doesn't help if there's another await in the bar function, but foo() is still not awaited. (Using OPs example)
